# Rails Tutorial (by Michael Hartl), Lesson 9, cant sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I have looked at similar errors but not only will my test wont pass, the script will not sign in a user.

> Failures:
>
> Finished in 0.41649 seconds 31 examples, 2 failures
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:48 #
>   SessionsController GET 'new' POST 'create' success should sign the
>   user in rspec ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:54 #
>   SessionsController GET 'new' POST 'create' success should redirect to
>   the user show page
>
> Done.
>
> Error upon signin: NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
>
> undefined method `authenticate' for #
>   Rails.root: /Users/lancevelasco/Development/appsample
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'

Code

user.rb

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  name               :string(255)
#  email              :string(255)
#  created_at         :datetime         not null
#  updated_at         :datetime         not null
#  encrypted_password :string(255)
#  salt               :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor   :password
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }    
  validates :password, :presence => true,
                        :confirmation => true,
                        :length => { :within => 6..40 }

  before_save :encrypt_password

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end


  def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil  if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password) 
  end

  def authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
    user = find_by_id(id)
    (user && user.salt == cookie_salt ) ? user : nil
  end

  private
  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
      secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
      end   

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end     
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @title = "Sign in"
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email],
                             params[:session][:password])
    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
      render 'new'
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in_(user)
    cookies.permanent.signed[:remember_token] = [user.id, user.salt]
    current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user || user_from_remember_token    
  end

  private

    def user_from_remember_token
      User.authenticate_with_salt()
    end

    def remember_token
      cookies.signed[:remember_token] || [nil,nil]
    end
end
```

user_controller_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SessionsController do

  render_views

    describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get 'new'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
       get :new
       response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign in")
     end

     describe "POST 'create'" do

       describe "failure" do

          before(:each) do
            @attr = { :email => "", :password => ""}
          end 

          it "should re-render the new page" do
            post :create,  :session => @attr 
            response.should render_template('new')
          end

          it "should have the right title" do
            post :create, :session => @attr
          end

          it "should have an error message" do
            post :create, :session => @attr
            flash.now[:error].should =~ /invalid/i
          end
       end

       describe "success" do

         before(:each) do
           @user= Factory(:user)
           @attr = { :email => @user.email, :password => @user.password }
         end

         it "should sign the user in" do
           post :create, :session => @attr
           controller.current_user.should == @user
           controller.should  be_signed_in
         end

         it "should redirect to the user show page" do
           post :create, :session => @attr
           response.should redirect_to(user_path(@user))
         end

       end

     end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, Michael Hartl used to use bcrypt to handle his authentication ([has_secure_password](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password)").  Looks like he opted to drop this and write his own authentication (looks like in order to add a salt...very good indeed).

You have in user.rb:

```
def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
  user = find_by_email(email)
  return nil  if user.nil?
  return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password) 
end
```

So as you can see, you need to pass the email to the authenticate method as well, and since it also grabs the user, you can simplify the session#create method.  Try this:

```
def create
  user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
  if user.nil?
    flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
    render 'new'
  else
    sign_in user
    redirect_back_or user
  end
end
```

Comment: This is very similar to the code that already exists in sessions_controller.rb ... What you are saying is to have a def create in both files?

Answer (score 1):

Now you call authenticate on object of User, but if I remember right, you declared authenticate as method of User class (like static method in java, for instance), not an object of User. That is why you get NoMethodError and so you should use something like Kubee method call:

```
user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
```

Comment: It still failed with that error using that code instead of


`user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_back_or user`

Comment: use not user.authenticate, but User.authenticate, capital U. user is object (variable) of class(type) User. authenticate is method not of object, but of class.

Comment: changing it to User.authenticate with a capital U gives a new error  
  
`Failures:

  1) SessionsController GET 'new' POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:36:in `authenticate'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:49:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

`

Comment: and  
'
  2) SessionsController GET 'new' POST 'create' success should redirect to the user show page
     Failure/Error: post :create, :session => @attr
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:36:in `authenticate'
     # ./app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:55:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>''

Comment: you should use User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password]). You must pass email and password, because in user.rb you defined authenticate as User.authenticate(email, submitted_password) - both parameters are required to call authenticate.

Comment: It is calling both user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && User.authenticate(params[:session][:email]

Its saying if both email and password are there then complete the sign in action

Answer (score 0):

It was a rather simple fix.

In session_helper

def sign_in_(user)

should of read

def sign_in(user)

And in the application_controller

add
  include SessionsHelper

Answer (score 0):

yes , i Successfully, thank you. 
i was used this

```
def User.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
user = find_by_email(email)
return nil if user.nil?
return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
end
```

and then

```
def create
user= User.authenticate(params[:session][:email]
params[:session][:password])
if user.nil?
flash.now[:error] ="Invalid email/password combination."
@title = "sign in"
render 'new'
else
sign_in user
redirect_to user
end
end
```